# Custom WordPress plugin, getting "rest_invalid_handler" error message when registering a new REST API endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a custom plugin for WordPress. But when I try to register a new API endpoint I am getting a "The handler for the route is invalid" error.

Here's my code:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: myPlugin
 * Plugin URI: http://meshcurrent.online
 * Description: my own plugin 1
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: MeshCurrent
 * Author URI: http://meshcurrent.online
 */
 
   add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'posts', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wl_posts',
    ]);

});


?>
```

This is my site's own JSON: https://meshcurrent.online/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

This is working.

But my PHP code is returning an error like the one shown below when I go to https://meshcurrent.online/wp/wp-json/wl/v1/posts

```json
{
"code": "rest_invalid_handler",
"message": "The handler for the route is invalid.",
"data": {
"status": 500
}
}
```

Note that the plugin is activated.

Comment: please check is your plugin active? and save permalink too

Comment: my plugin is active. But I don't understand what you want to say telling save permalink

Comment: WordPress caches rewrites, so if there's any major change you sometimes have to flush them which can be done by going to the admin area for permalinks and just clicking Save without making changes

Comment: I tried but still not working

Comment: Do you have a function that is globally available called `wl_posts`? Also, make sure to define [`permission_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#permissions-callback)